# How to get photo URL which is inside web application

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

This is a web application which shows all the candidates of 2018 election in Brazil. I want to get the photo URL, so I can download it. I tried to read the HTML and get the element, but, since it's an application, it seems that I can not get the photo. It says that "photo" is empty.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2018/2022802018/RJ/190000602140"

photo <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath = "//*/img") %>%
  html_attr("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can retrieve that photo using wget or by entering URL into a browser, so you should be able to retrieve it. This is the image xpath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[1]/img
```

Retrieving the image with wget show it should be possible to retrieve it:

1. Right click on the the photo and selectet "copy image location".
2. Pasting that URL into a new tab shows the image.
3. Pasting the URL into a wget command retrieves the image.

Here's the wget command I used:

```
wget --nostst http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/candidaturas/oficial/2018/BR/RJ/2022802018/190000602140/foto_1533686884282.jpg
```

[Screen shot of image being retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSyGa.png)